# JMeter with Java Swing Application

Tags: java, swing, testing, jmeter, load-testing

When intergrating with web application, we need to provide the URL and Port number, so that JMeter can start recording.

But if you have a Java Swing Application, is it possible to intergrate with JMeter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From their web site :

```
Can load and performance test many different server types:

    Web - HTTP, HTTPS
    SOAP
    Database via JDBC
    LDAP
    JMS
    Mail - SMTP(S), POP3(S) and IMAP(S)
    Native commands or shell scripts
```

So I'm going to have to say no...

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of effort this should be entirely possible given that JMeter is written in Java. You can [download the source code from here](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi), and once you have that it will be a case of finding the right classes in the source code which run tests using JMeter & report the results, and you should then be able to call these from your own application.